# Copying rows from one file to other based on a different file

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2003

I have one Excel file that contains 2 columns: `Words` & `Definition` (3000 rows). I have another Excel file which contains only `words` not definition (200 rows).

How can I extract only those rows (Words and definition- from 3000) which are there in the 2nd Excel file (200 rows)?

Basically i want to filter those .

In SQL i would write

```
Select * from table1 where table1.words=table2.words
```

How do i implement this in excel ? 
Please give me the procedure too...

Comment: This question is tagged [excel-2007](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2007) and [excel-2003](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2003) -- which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only the value from 2 columns you need to copy, I'd use the [VLOOKUP()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) function in the 2nd file to look up and return the matches from the first file. Don't forget to set the  `range_lookup` parameter to `false`.

If you really need to copy the entire row, then a loop in a VBA macro would be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I need to copy the whole row ( `word` and `definition` )  based on the `word` in  the second excel sheet

Comment: But `Word` and `Definition` just sounds like 2 columns to me - why copy the whole row?

Comment: Then I'd suggest a VBA macro would be more suitable than a function.

Comment: @AdiMathur After doing the VLOOKUP in a helper column, filter the column by the matching value and then copy those rows to another workbook/sheet.

Comment: @JP. - I need some help , i have now 3 coloums ( word , meaning and 3rd coloum important words ) 

I want to select those words and meaning which are there in `important words`

Comment: @AdiMathur Update your question.

Comment: @Widor - Can you please guide me , I dont know VBA macro

Comment: @Widor- I get an error `the values used in the formula is of the wrong data type`

Comment: @AdiMathur We can guide you once you've made a start but I can't write the code for you, sorry.

Comment: @Widor - It worked !! :) , How can i copy this into another sheet , when i copy past the definitions are not coming , insted the reference `=VLOOKUP(A150:A1279,#REF!,2,FALSE)` comes .

Comment: @AdiMathur Right-click and choose `Paste Special`, then paste `Values`.